# git in ubuntu with error message " undefined symbol: __gmpn_cnd_add_n"

Tags: git, ubuntu

I plan to connect my local repository with remote one in ubuntu 16.04. I conduct following steps:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/*****/****.git 
git pull origin master
```

but when I run

```
git pull origin master
```

error message as follows are shown:

```
 git-remote-https: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4: undefined symbol: __gmpn_cnd_add_n
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

After further searching, I eventually get the answer.
Firstly, I run

```
ls -l /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so*
```

and it returns

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Sep 17 05:25 /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so -> libgmp.so.10.1.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Sep 17 05:25 /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10 -> libgmp.so.10.1.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 491264 Sep 17 03:57 /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 531960 Sep 17 05:25 /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10.1.3
```

and I just run command line as follows:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so*
```

Finally, it works. Hope it can help.

Comment: I believe there is a typo and the first command you ran was `ls -l /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so*` 
The `ls` command is used to list files and directories in a directory, and the `-l` option is used to display the detailed information about the files.
(not rm /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so*)

Answer (score 1):

As [seen here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=810112):

> This usually means that, for some unknown reason, you are linking to a
>   too old version of gmp at runtime.
>   The gmp-6.1 pcakage you have installed ought to be new enough, but check with `ldd` on the failing programs which library `.so` files really are picked up.

So: `ldd $(which git)`
See [this post](https://techoverflow.net/2015/12/06/solving-libhogweed-so-2-undefined-symbol-__gmpn_cnd_add_n/) as an example.

And see "[How to install the latest gmp library in 1x.04?](https://askubuntu.com/a/212083/5470)".

The [OP Hannankan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7931705/hannankan) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799343/git-in-ubuntu-with-error-message-undefined-symbol-gmpn-cnd-add-n#comment84614807_48800656):

> You are partly right as far as I know. I am linking to a too old version of gmp at runtime.
>   But I just remove the symbolic and the problem is fixed.

Comment: Your are partly right as far as I know. I am linking to a too old version of gmp at runtime.

Comment: But I just remove the symbolic and the problem is fixed.

Comment: @HannanKan OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the following error message:

```
symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.6: undefined symbol: __gmpn_cnd_add_n
```

The `sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so*` command is very powerful, so be careful with it or any other remove command which includes a `*`. I used the `*` with the remove command and it removed the symlink as well and then things were seriously broken. One of the error messages was:

```
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading shared libraries: libhogweed.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I could not even do a `apt-get update`. I finally resorted to formatting the machine.